# HTML Canvas does not refresh (2)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I was told to ask a more specific question etc....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="RoomCanvas" width="300" height="200">
<!-- ************************************* -->
<!-- The wall is always here               -->
<!-- ************************************* --> 
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
<script>
var c = document.getElementById("RoomCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 200);

alert("clear");



doWall("blue", 0);

x = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  x = x + i;
}

alert("left there");

doWall("pink", 47);


function doWall(theColor, xlocation){
  ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.moveTo(xlocation, xlocation);
     ctx.lineTo(xlocation, 100);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 8;
  ctx.strokeStyle = theColor;
  ctx.stroke();
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The Problems:
1 - clear rectangle does not work until the program stops running!
2 - the blue line does not appear until the program stops running!
3 - the pink line does not appear until the program stops running!

My application needs to put the blue line out when the program is doing something.  When the program finishes what it is doing the pink line is to be displayed along with the blue line.

What good is a canvas that does not show anything until all the drawing is done?

I hope this better describes the problem.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Charlie

Comment: When you're drawing, you're actually setting bits in a part of the computer's RAM. They might not appear on the screen immediately. Using `alert()` for instance will stop the browser dead in its tracks and won't display changes that were made immediately before.

Comment: JS and page repainting are sharing the same thread, nothing is updated on the page when a "program" is running. It's notable, that `alert` behaves differently across browsers (related to repaint), use the console for debugging messages instead.

Comment: What is your for loop even for? It just ends up with an `x` value used once that is basically `!10000` (factorial) which is much larger than any x  value... Otherwise, yes, replace the alerts. Also, since you aren't _ever_ waiting for anything, the whole script will just run and the output drawn once. In the meanwhile, your computer just hangs being occupied computing your 10000 factorial.

Comment: Looks like you ignored my advice to use the intervals or timeout, instead you still using those alerts...

Comment: I guess I still didn't make myself clear.  I only put the alerts in so I could "see"  the progress of the program.  The for loop is precisely my problem.  It was made to show that there was "work to be done."  The idea is that the blue line should show while the "work was being done."  I can't use a timing function I have no idea how long it will take for the work to be done.  I merely want the blue line to show until the work is done and then the pink line to show.  I guess this cannot be done.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using timeouts

- The blue line will draw after 500 milliseconds
- The pink line will draw after 2000 milliseconds

```js
var c = document.getElementById("RoomCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

setTimeout(() => { doWall("blue", 10) }, 500);
setTimeout(() => { doWall("pink", 47) }, 2000);

function doWall(theColor, xlocation) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(xlocation, xlocation);
  ctx.lineTo(xlocation, 100);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 8;
  ctx.strokeStyle = theColor;
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="RoomCanvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

---

Here is another example using click events:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("RoomCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

function doWall(theColor, xlocation) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height)
  ctx.moveTo(xlocation, xlocation);
  ctx.lineTo(xlocation, 100);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 8;
  ctx.strokeStyle = theColor;
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="doWall('red', 10)">red</button>
<button onclick="doWall('blue', 20)">blue</button>
<button onclick="doWall('pink', 30)">pink</button>
<button onclick="doWall('black', 40)">black</button>

<br>
<canvas id="RoomCanvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```